How to change the class of elements in a list?
I have a string for input with comma seperated elements. - marks = 'marks1,marks2,marks3'
Using split function I got list of marks. - marks = marks.split(',')
This gives us 'marks' a list with elements as srting however I want integers as elements. marks[int]
Do we have an in-built function to convert the same or do we need to use the following for-loop?
for i, m in enumerate(marks):
    marks[i] = int(m)

The above loop works but I just want to know if we have some in-built function

What integer should, for example, marks1 become?

If your string is 'marks1,marks2,marks3', you can't convert it directly to integers by casting, as it contains non-numeric characters.
But, if you used it to explain your problem and string is actually like '31,78,45', you can convert it to a list of int with list comprehension:
marks = [int(m) for m in marks]

marks = '31,78,45'
marks = marks.split(',')
marks = [int(m) for m in marks]


Use a list comprehension.
>>> marks = marks.split(',')
>>> [(int)(e.split('marks')[1]) for e in marks.split(',')]
[1, 2, 3]
>>> 


So, you can use regular expressions (import re), which are built to get a list of all the included digits.
>>> import re
>>> marks = 'marks1,marks2,marks3,marks4,marks5,marks10,marks4093'
>>> list(map(int, re.findall(r'(\d+)', marks)))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 4093]

This will also help you to track if you have different markers and you are only interesseted in a specific keyword before the integer.
>>> marks = 'marks1,narks2,carks3,marks4,Sarks5,marks10,tarks4093'
>>> list(map(int, re.findall(r'marks(\d+)', marks)))
[1, 4, 10]

Make sure the brackets (...) are around the elements you are interested in. In this case, numeric values. Otherwise, the int conversion will fail.
